# How can I display images from a local file on a web page using c#?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, webforms

I am trying to display an image using an address of where it is located in the file. Currently I have the image stored in the content folder of my web application, but I do not know how to access it there or display it on the page itself. This is what I currently have.

```
    Image image = Image.FromFile(@"~\Content\img\toendra.JPG");
```

Comment: You know HTML right? You know what an `img` tag is? Is this Web Forms? Or MVC?

Comment: Yes I am aware of what an image tag is, and this is Web Forms.

Answer (score 0):

In Web Forms, we use the [Image control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.image(v=vs.110).aspx) to display images. Put this in your markup:

```
<asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Content/img/toendra.JPG" />
```

Comment: Ok, now if I wanted to click a button, and then depending on which button I click the corresponding image would show up, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: @J.Daxter You would research how to do that. And you would attempt to write some code that does it. And if you get stuck, you would create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and explain your situation in a new question.